# Combining prayers In certain cases

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, combining-prayers

I have classes from 9 a.m to 4 p.m, on Sundays, (Asr time 3:45). Is it permitted for me to combine my prayers(zuhr and asr) since there is no place for me to pray in the tuition centre?